# How to fetch web service data in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, firefox, google-chrome

I am doing a project in HTML, JavaScript only. 
I have a function that that get the data from web service(.asmx), and it is working fine. But in Firefox, Chrome its not working. Here is the code, please verify:

```
function CreateXMLHttpRequest()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}   

function CallWebService() {


    var objXMLHttpRequest = CreateXMLHttpRequest();
    objXMLHttpRequest.open ("POST", 
                            "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/WebServicesp/WebMethods.asmx", 
                            false);
    objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    var packet='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
                <soap:Envelope  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Body></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

    objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
    var res=objXMLHttpRequest.responseText;

    alert(res);   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What errors do you get?

Comment: Use a tool like Firebug, watch the http response.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
function CallService() {

jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url/Service1.asmx/servicename",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });


}
function OnSuccess(data, status) {
alert("success");

    alert(data.d);


}

function OnError(request, status, error) {


    alert(status);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    CallService();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be getting an js error about  **cross domain ajax request**, in that case it would work fine in internet explorer but not on other browsers because IE does not enforce cross-domain security policy.
this will help you understand cross domain, [Cross-domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708519/cross-domain-error) 
if thats the case you need to tr JSONP or curl to get data.
hope it helps

can you post the error msg from firebug console?

Comment: in chrome.. try right click your page -> Inspect element. look in the console tab for any msg

Comment: @austin: "IE does not enforce cross-domain security policy" - why would you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Is the html page being served from the same domain as the endpoint url of the webservice? If no, then its the cross-domain violation issue as pointed out here by others. Check for any javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install plugin called tamper data
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/?src=search

or software called fiddler
http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Those will show you the actual requests and responses, so you'll be able to find the problem in the real requests if there is any.